# Symmetrize bones not working as expected

Tags: rigging

I feel like an idiot for not being able to follow this tutorial, but it seems things have changed. https://youtu.be/Q9f-WVs3ghI?t=1013

I dont want to follow the tutorial exactly because the FlipNames has changed, it leaves the .001 extension.

If I select W>symmetrize parent bones stay on the left side, and only the children bones are copied(and parented to the left side).

[image]

Here's the file https://tinyurl.com/y99pl9dt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You didn't put a .L at the end of ‘Bone.006’ and ‘Bone.007’ on the hand, and ‘Bone’ on the foot. So when you press W>Symmetrize it doesn’t make a copy of those bones, and the copied children on the right side are still connected to the parents on left side.

Comment: I thought I just needed to name them differently, but it looks like Blender is literally looking for a  ".L" (Or ".R" if you make a right-sided rig)  at the end of the name of all selected bones for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: Ouaaaah !!!! I watched a tutorial but didn't expect the naming to have an influence. Thanks ! It works.

Answer (score 0):

The error is to change the names the symmetry only works with the names that have a tag from the side. Example all the names with the tag `.L` will be mirror to `.R`